# Python3 recursively multiply items in hierarchical list

Tags: python, list, recursion

I have a list as follows:

```
list = ['Item', 'Qty'], ['2', '1'], ['3', '1'], ['4', '1'], ['4.1', '2'], ['4.2', '2'], ['4.3', '2'], ['5', '1'], ['5.1', '1'], ['5.1.1', '1'], ['5.1.2', '1'], ['5.1.2.1', '1'], ['5.1.2.1.1', '1'], ['5.1.3', '1'], ['5.1.3.1', '1'], ['5.2', '1'], ['5.2.1', '1'], ['5.2.2', '1'], ['5.2.2.1', '1'], ['5.2.2.2', '1'], ['5.3', '1'], ['5.4', '1'], ['5.5', '1']
```

Each item in the list has a quantity field. The list is structured in a hierarchical manner such that each item has a parent or perhaps multiple parents apart from the top level items.

eg. Item 5.1.2.1 has parents 5.1.2, 5.1 and 5 and has one child 5.1.2.1.1. However item 5 only has multiple children.

What I would like to accomplish is to multiply the quantity of an item by the quantities of all its parents in a recursive manner and update the quantities in the list. Or a new list can be generated with the updated values.

I am having some difficulty getting it to work correctly as this is my first attempt at recursion.

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid list to me.  Have you tried running the code you just pasted?  Also try not to name variables after actual python data structures like `list`

Comment: It would also be good to see what you've tried so far so you can explain to us exactly what part you are having trouble with.

Comment: As written, your `list` is a `tuple` of lists.

Comment: Well, since each item (eg.`'5.2.2.2'` has `'1'`) had `'1'`, then I assume that the product will always be `1`. Is this right, or do you have some different data in mind?

Comment: This question is very vague, you need to show the output of your expected behaviour as well as some effort that people contributing are not just answering your homework..

Comment: Hi   
I suggest you improve your question, add some examples, some code and make it more clear what you want to achieve. Have a look here => [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Reg Grobler Add the expected Output, otherwise other user can't understand what you mean, they can help you but the question should be more cleear

Comment: Is there a reason for needing to do this recurively? Because with Pandas, if you simply obtain the Parent Item and then do a `groupby()` you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little something to help get you started:

```
def search(ex_list, myItem, myQty):
    myQty = int(myQty)
    for item, qty in ex_list:
        if myItem.find(item) == 0 and item != myItem:
            myQty *= search(ex_list, item, qty) #Calling the function on the parent and multiplying its result
    return myQty
```

This code leverages the fact that any parent will be a substring of its children. That is, that the string `5.1` is inside of `5.1.2`.

If you call all the function with any particular value (ex: `search(ex_list, "5.1.1", "1")`), it will give you the proper answer.

Problems with this code that you might want to solve:

1. This function only returns the value but it doesn't store it in the proper format
2. The recursion has a lot of redundancies. For example, if I called the function with `"5.1.2.1.1"` and later with `"5.1.2"`, the code will manually compute the values for all of the parents, even though both values share some of them. I would lookup Dynamic Programming concepts like memoization [One of my favorite tutorials](https://www.educative.io/courses/grokking-dynamic-programming-patterns-for-coding-interviews/m2G1pAq0OO0) for some info on how to make it better.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is transfert this data to a usable format with indexing on the  item keys.

Then you should build a hierarchical structure to represent the items in a parent-child tree.  This can be achieved using a dictionary of dictionaries of dictionaries ... (i.e. the structure itself is recursive)

Once you have that, you can endeavour to write a recursive function.

```
data = [['2', '1'], ['3', '1'], ['4', '1'], ['4.1', '2'], ['4.2', '2'],
        ['4.3', '2'], ['5', '2'], ['5.1', '3'], ['5.1.1', '4'],
        ['5.1.2', '5'], ['5.1.2.1', '6'], ['5.1.2.1.1', '7'],
        ['5.1.3', '8'], ['5.1.3.1', '9'], ['5.2', '8'], ['5.2.1', '7'],
        ['5.2.2', '6'], ['5.2.2.1', '5'], ['5.2.2.2', '4'], ['5.3', '3'],
        ['5.4', '2'], ['5.5', '1']]
```

Convert the data to a usable/indexed structure:

```
amounts = { k:int(v) for k,v in data }    # {item:amount}
```

Create the tree structure:

```
nodes   = { k:dict() for k,_ in data } # node indexing starting with no children
root    = nodes[""]= dict()            # add the root node
for key,_ in data:                     # link nodes ...
    parentKey = ".".join(key.split(".")[:-1]) # get key of immediate parent
    nodes[parentKey][key] = nodes[key]        # link each child to it's parent

print(root) # the recursive dictionary

{'2': {}, 
 '3': {}, 
 '4': {'4.1': {}, 
       '4.2': {}, 
       '4.3': {}}, 
 '5': {'5.1': {'5.1.1': {}, 
               '5.1.2': {'5.1.2.1': {'5.1.2.1.1': {}}}, 
               '5.1.3': {'5.1.3.1': {}}}, 
       '5.2': {'5.2.1': {}, 
               '5.2.2': {'5.2.2.1': {}, '5.2.2.2': {}}}, 
       '5.3': {}, 
       '5.4': {}, 
       '5.5': {}}}
```

The recursive function:

```
def propagate(amounts,node,prod=1):   # propagate multiplier from parent
    for key,subNodes in node.items():             
        amounts[key] *= prod                      # adjust each subnode's amount
        propagate(amounts,subNodes,amounts[key])  # propagate to subnodes
```

output:

```
print("BEFORE:",*sorted(amounts.items()),sep="\n")
propagate(amounts,root)
print("AFTER:",*sorted(amounts.items()),sep="\n")
```

BEFORE:

```
('2', 1)
('3', 1)
('4', 1)
('4.1', 2)
('4.2', 2)
('4.3', 2)
('5', 2)
('5.1', 3)
('5.1.1', 4)
('5.1.2', 5)
('5.1.2.1', 6)
('5.1.2.1.1', 7)
('5.1.3', 8)
('5.1.3.1', 9)
('5.2', 8)
('5.2.1', 7)
('5.2.2', 6)
('5.2.2.1', 5)
('5.2.2.2', 4)
('5.3', 3)
('5.4', 2)
('5.5', 1)
```

AFTER:

```
('2', 1)
('3', 1)
('4', 1)
('4.1', 2)
('4.2', 2)
('4.3', 2)
('5', 2)            
('5.1', 6)           # 3 x 2    from 5
('5.1.1', 24)        # 4 x 6    from 5.1
('5.1.2', 30)        # 5 x 6    from 5.1
('5.1.2.1', 180)     # 6 x 30   from 5.1.2
('5.1.2.1.1', 1260)  # 7 x 180  from 5.1.2.1
('5.1.3', 48)        # 8 x 6    from 5.1
('5.1.3.1', 432)     # 9 x 48   from 5.1.3 
('5.2', 16)          # 8 x 2    from 5
('5.2.1', 112)       # 7 x 16   from 5.2
('5.2.2', 96)        # 6 x 16   from 5.2
('5.2.2.1', 480)     # 5 x 96   from 5.2.1
('5.2.2.2', 384)     # 4 x 96   from 5.2.1
('5.3', 6)           # 3 x 2    from 5
('5.4', 4)           # 2 x 2    from 5
('5.5', 2)           # 1 x 2    from 5
```